# MVCGrid.Net - Paging not limiting results or page numbers not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvcgrid.net

I am using MVCGrid.Net and I am trying to add pagination to the grid, Here is my code:

```
GridDefinition<DepositLog> def = new GridDefinition<DepositLog>();

GridColumn<DepositLog> ID = new GridColumn<DepositLog>();
ID.ColumnName = "ID";
ID.HeaderText = "ID";
ID.HtmlEncode = false;
ID.ValueTemplate = "<input type='text' name='ID' value='{Value}' class='form-control' />";
ID.ValueExpression = (i, c) => i.id.ToString();
def.AddColumn(ID);

GridColumn<DepositLog> PayTo = new GridColumn<DepositLog>();
PayTo.ColumnName = "PayTo";
PayTo.HeaderText = "PayTo";
PayTo.HtmlEncode = false;
PayTo.ValueTemplate = "<input type='text' name='PayTo' value='{Value}' class='form-control' />";
PayTo.ValueExpression = (i, c) => i.PayTo.ToString();
def.AddColumn(PayTo);

GridColumn<DepositLog> Category = new GridColumn<DepositLog>();
Category.ColumnName = "Category";
Category.HeaderText = "Category";
Category.HtmlEncode = false;
Category.ValueTemplate = "<input type='text' name='Category' value='{Value}' class='form-control' />";
Category.ValueExpression = (i, c) => i.Category.ToString();
def.AddColumn(Category);

def.Paging = true;
def.ItemsPerPage = 10;

def.RetrieveData = (options) =>
{
    return new QueryResult<DepositLog>()
    {
        Items = _modelItems,
        TotalRecords = 0
    };
};

try
{
    MVCGridDefinitionTable.GetDefinition<DepositLog>("DepositLogGrid");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MVCGridDefinitionTable.Add("DepositLogGrid", def);
}
```

I followed this demo here: http://mvcgrid.net/demo/paging

My code is a little bit different because I have multiple Controllers each with a grid, so I define my grid in the Controller, but yea...my paging is not appearing and all the results come up...what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
def.Paging = true;
            def.ItemsPerPage = 25;
            def.MaxItemsPerPage = 25;

            def.RetrieveData = (context) =>
            {

                var options = context.QueryOptions;

                var result = new QueryResult<DepositLog>();

                var query = _modelItems.AsQueryable();

                result.TotalRecords = query.Count();

                if (options.GetLimitOffset().HasValue)
                {
                    query = query.Skip(options.GetLimitOffset().Value).Take(options.GetLimitRowcount().Value);
                }
                result.Items = query.ToList();

                return result;
            };
```